# Different treatment of parameters: lambdas vs. defines in Scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, r5rs, chicken-scheme

I have two constructs that I expected to be functionally the same, but they are not and I can't figure out why.

### Using define

```
(define (x2 . b)
  (display b)
  (newline))

(x2 3 4 5) => (3 4 5)
```

### Using lambda

```
((lambda (. b) 
   (display b) 
   (newline)) 
   3 4 5) => Error: invalid use of `.'
```

In the [R5RS](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/The%20R5RS%20standard), both [definitions](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/The%20R5RS%20standard#definitions) and [lambdas](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/The%20R5RS%20standard#procedures) accept . To make them behave identically I could construct the lambda like this:

```
((lambda b
   (display b)
   (newline))
   3 4 5) => (3 4 5)
```

That is one of the valid constructs listed in report's definition of formal parameters. But if I attempt to use it with define, it results in an argument number mismatch error.

```
(define (x2 b)
  (display b)
  (newline))

(x2 3 4 5) => Error: bad argument count
```

I thought `(define (x y) y)` was just syntactic sugar for `(define x (lambda (y) y))`. It seems like that is true only in most cases. Can anyone explain the rationale for the different behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These expressions represent an anonymous procedure with a fixed arity:

```
(define (x y) y)
(define (x y z) z)
```

And they're equivalent to:

```
(define x (lambda (y) y))
(define x (lambda (y z) z))
```

But take this procedure, with a variable number of arguments:

```
(define (x . y) y)
```

It's only equivalent to:

```
(define x (lambda y y))
```

Continuing with the examples, this procedure has a single mandatory parameter and the others are variable:

```
(define (x y . z) z)
```

And its equivalent form would be:

```
(define x (lambda (y . z) z))
```

So, the syntax is a bit different between the implicit/explicit use of a `lambda` for defining procedures with a variable number of arguments, which is what the dot notation is used for in this case.

Also, syntax like `'( . b)` is invalid, because in this case the dot notation is representing an *improper list*, that is, a list whose last element is not the empty list. On the other hand, this is valid: `'(a . b)`. This explains why the expression `(lambda ( . x) x)` is invalid; and given that `(lambda (x) x)` represents an anonymous procedure with a single mandatory parameter, we're left with `(lambda x x)` for representing an anonymous procedure with only a variable number of arguments and no mandatory arguments.

As far as I know the only rationale for why things are like this is by convention, and possibly because it's easier to parse.

Answer (score 2):

`(. arguments)` is invalid syntax. The dot indicates the separation between **two** parts of a pair and you have no first part here. I do see that you actually mean `arguments` here and that it should not be a list at all.

The define that looks like this:

```
(define (name . arguments)
  ..)
```

Are the same as:

```
(define name 
  (lambda arguments
    ..))
```

An example with one argument:

```
(define (name arg1 . arguments)
  ..)
```

Becomes

```
(define name 
  (lambda (arg1 . arguments)
    ..))
```

The reason is simple: `(cdr '(name . arguments)) ; ==> arguments` and `(cdr '(name arg1 . arguments)) ; ==> '(arg1 . arguments)`.